# Why does the dataGridView works only on my own computer?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have recently created a task managment software that is based on displaying tasks inside a dataGridView that is binded to database through the function below:

```
public void Bind(string sqlquery)
    {
        mySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(
            "SERVER=localhost;" +
            "DATABASE=test;" +
            "UID=root;" +
            "PASSWORD=Pa$$123;");
        try
        {
            mySqlConnection.Open();
            string query = sqlquery;

            mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, mySqlConnection);
            mySqlCommandBuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(mySqlDataAdapter);

            mySqlDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = mySqlCommandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
            mySqlDataAdapter.DeleteCommand = mySqlCommandBuilder.GetDeleteCommand();
            mySqlDataAdapter.InsertCommand = mySqlCommandBuilder.GetInsertCommand();

            dataTable = new DataTable();
            mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

            bindingSource = new BindingSource();
            bindingSource.DataSource = dataTable;

            dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource;
        }
        catch {

            notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "Erreur de connexion";
            notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "La connexion au serveur est échouée, nous éssayons de se connecter à nouveau, si un ce problème dure plus de 5 minutes ou si vous rencontrez des problèmes d'affichage nous vous conseillons de fermer l'application et la relancer à nouveau";
            notifyIcon1.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Warning;
            notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(5000);
        }


        //close mysql conn
        mySqlConnection.Dispose();
    }
```

Everything is working as expected in my Computer running Windows 7 (x86) but when I try to use the application on other computers, i get the datagridview blank and i cannot see any data displayed.

Why does the dataGridView work only on my computer and not on other  computers ?

**EDIT:**
 I'm targeting .NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile and I used VS2010 Express Edition for app deployement and I tried to change the Target Net Framework to older versions but the results are same.

I also tried to use the Application on 4 other computers : Windows XP SP3, Windows 7 (x86), Windows 7 (x64) and the results are the same. No data are displayed inside the dataGridView except when i run the application in my own computer.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Since you missed the error, try adding logging to the error handling rather than just showing the BalloonTip in case it is not visible for whatever reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are connecting to Localhost

```
mySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(
        "SERVER=localhost;" +
        "DATABASE=test;" +
        "UID=root;" +
        "PASSWORD=Pa$$123;");
```

This is presumably on your development machine, you need to change the connection to use the real server on the network

Comment: Yes i should wait at least 9 minute to accept the answer. I will mark your answer as accepted. You saved my day ! thankya